# mysqli time & date insert

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

I'm trying to insert the date that a user registered on a site into mysql but for some odd reason im not getting it insert right, Im using this query below

```
  $connect->query("INSERT INTO `users` (username, email, password, name, country, signup_date) VALUES ('". $username ."', '". $email ."', '". $password ."', '". $fname . " " . $lname ."', '". $country ."', '".time()."')");
```

I'm getting an amount insert into the signup_date but its obviously jumbled up, any ideas?

Comment: what is the dataType of column  `signup_date`?

Comment: what is the `time()` function's output? what you expect it to output?

Comment: Without knowing the database structure we can't help you. Try using `desc users` in your database console to show us your table structure. From there, you can use the database documentation on that column type to determine the format of time. Then you can use the php `time()` and `date(...)` methods to format the string as you need it to be.  Once you have that you can edit your question to ask what formating string you should use to the php method to get the expected database input

Comment: **WARNING**: Using manual escaping is extremely error prone and a single mistake can lead to a crippling [SQL injection bug](http://bobby-tables.com/). Whenever possible use **prepared statements**. These are quite straightforward to do in [`mysqli`](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php) and [PDO](http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepared-statements.php) where any user-supplied data is specified with a `?` or `:name` indicator that’s later populated using `bind_param` or `execute` depending on which one you’re using.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Php's `time()` function [returns](http://php.net/manual/en/function.time.php) the unix timestamp. However, MySQL expects date and time values to be provided in `'YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM:SS'` format. Just format your time value within php to match the format MySQL expects.

Comment: Yeah this works, sorry was pretty much common sense but i was just getting confused.

Answer (score 1):

İf the type of signup_date is datetime you can use `date("Y-m-d H:i:s"`) instead of time() to get a formated datetime

Answer (score 0):

You can use mysql functions `NOW() OR CURDATE()`

```
"INSERT INTO `users` (username, email, password, name, country, signup_date) VALUES ('". $username ."', '". $email ."', '". $password ."', '". $fname . " " . $lname ."', '". $country ."', NOW())"
```

Comment: This may yield different results than the data coming from php (timezones). On database level timestamp field would even be more efficient.

Answer (score 0):

Change the column dataType and make it `timestamp`.

In Its default column write `CURRENT_TIMESTAMP` and don't insert anything inside your `signup_date` column. It will automatically insert the current date.

Answer (score 0):

You can set the datatype for signup_date to be Date from your database and use `NOW()` function in your query .

```
  $connect->query("INSERT INTO `users` (username, email, password, name, country, signup_date) VALUES ('". $username ."', '". $email ."', '". $password ."', '". $fname . " " . $lname ."', '". $country ."', '".NOW()."')");
```

If signup_date datatype was only `Date` and you used the above query the data will be in this format : `YYYY-MM-DD`

but if it was in `TIMESTAMP` datatype it will be in this format :  `YYYY-MM-DD HH:MI:SS`

so depends on what you need you can use .